# how to send an email with django rest framework

Tags: python, django, email, django-rest-framework

i have asked this question quite a lot of times in the python discord and other places but i still can't find out how to send an email to verify an account or reset a password in django rest framework.

i have watched these tutorials

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kKwPk5qPUs

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXg-b20Xusw&t=671s

https://saasitive.com/tutorial/django-rest-framework-reset-password/

https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

i have also tried djoser but that hasnt worked
and i have also tried the twilio sendgrid api
with this tutorial
https://www.mindbowser.com/integrating-sendgrid-with-django-rest-framework/

so does anyone have any answers on how to send an email with django rest framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Djoser then set this settings in your settings.py file.
It's work perfectly for account verification and reset password,etc. by email confirmation.

Docs : [djoser setting docs.](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#settings)

```
DJOSER = {
        'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'reset_password_confirm/{uid}/{token}',
        'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'username/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
        'ACTIVATION_URL': 'user_activation/{uid}/{token}',
        'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
        'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL':True,
        'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION':True,
        'USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION':True,
        'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE':True,
        'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE':True,
        'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_RETYPE':True,
        'PASSWORD_RESET_SHOW_EMAIL_NOT_FOUND':True,
        'USERNAME_RESET_SHOW_EMAIL_NOT_FOUND':True,
        # 'LOGIN_FIELD':"email",
    }
```

Comment: i have added that now, but how do implement it to my own user sign up view instead of using its default urls

Comment: hi i have watched the playlist but when i post a request in postman it says

```
TypeError: create_user() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'latitude', 'longitude', 'country', and 'postcode'
```
does it only use default fields like username and email and password or is there a way to specify which fields create_user() can take in?

Comment: If latitude,longitude,country and postcode is not mandatory when user create their new account then give `null=true` and `blank=true` or set `default`(default=''Ex.") or give `REQUIRED_FIELDS`..Ex. `country = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True,null=True)`.Visit this : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-custom-user-model-api-extending-abstractuser-in-django/